# Windows Form gets stuck on multiple async tasks

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async-await, task

I am trying to execute parallel methods, **but Form gets stuck whenever
I call them**.

Please correct what I am doing wrong. Here is the Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      var itemList = new List<string>() { "Field1", "Field2", "Field3" };

      await Task.WhenAll(itemList.Select(item =>
           new WorkToDo(item).StartWork()
           ));
    }
}

public class WorkToDo
{
    private string id;

    public WorkToDo(string id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public async Task<bool> StartWork()
    {
        Calculate();
        Analyze();
        SomeToDo();
        var result = Save();
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return result;
    }

    private bool Calculate()
    {
        //Some complex and time taking calculation will be here
        return true;
    }

    private bool Analyze()
    {
        //Some complex and time taking calculation will be here
        return true;
    }

    private bool SomeToDo()
    {
        //Some complex and time taking calculation will be here
        return true;
    }

    private bool Save()
    {
        //Some complex and time taking calculation will be here
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remember that normal async / await will still be performed on the UI thread.

So to be sure that a real long action is pushed to a background thread, you need to wrap it in Task.Run... like `Task.Run(() => Task.WhenAll(tasks));`

To complete the question a bit more ( seeing the other answer available ), Task.Run usage is not something to take lightly. It all depends on what sort of code needs to be wrapped.
There is a good write up series on this up on the blog of Stephen Cleary here http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-even-in.html so take some time to go through this and see what fits your project.

Or look here for some other details from Stephen https://stackoverflow.com/a/18015586

Comment: Yes, Now it is working. can you explain about Task.Run()? Is this code is good for long operations? Thank you

Comment: The main reason for Task.Run is indeed for "how can I run an operation on a background thread in a way that it's awaitable"

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you have is that `StartWork` *claims* to be asynchronous, and yet it isn't.  It does all of it's work synchronously.

Marking a method as `async` doesn't make it asynchronous.  it just allows you to use the `await` keyword from within that method.  If you perform long running synchronous operations from an `async` method then that method is still going to be doing that work synchronously.

There are really two approaches to take here.  If there are some number of the things done in `StartWork` that really are inherently asynchronous, then you need to wrap whatever synchronous CPU bound work you have in calls to `Task.Run` so that the synchronous work that you have can be done asynchronously in a thread pool thread.

If there is no inherently asynchronous operations you have to do in `StartWork` then *make the method clearly synchronous*.  Have it return a boolean, not a `Task`, and adjust the name to reflect the fact that it is synchronous.  Then have the caller that calls it use `Task.Run` to do that whole operation on a thread pool thread asynchronously.

Having `StartWork` *falsely claim* to be asynchronous, and then still using `Task.Run` to do the *purportedly* asynchronous work in another thread is going to be extremely confusing to other readers of your code, as there should be no reason to offload an asynchronous method to a non-UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, If you are using `Async` operation you don't need `Task.Run()` if you have `Sync Task` and do it asynchronously you need `Task.Run()`

> If you are using normal synchronous process just return `Task<T>` and use this `Task.Run(())` to use background thread to process. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17119610/1876572)

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var itemList = new List<string>() { "Field1", "Field2", "Field3" }; // more than 50 items 

    Task.Run(() => Task.WhenAll(tasks));
}


public class WorkToDo
{
 private string id;

 public WorkToDo(string id)
 {
     this.id = id;
 }

 public async Task<bool> StartWork()
 {
   var t1 = Calculate();
   var t2 = Analyze();
   var t3 = SomeToDo();

    //Assuming you need to do all this before you save
    // so wait for the all.

    await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2,t3);
    var result = await Save();
    return result;
}

private async Task<bool> Calculate()
{
    //Some complex and time taking calculation will be here
    //Assuming here you have some DoAsync() method
    return true;
}

private async Task<bool> Analyze()
{
    //Some complex and time taking calculation will be here
    return true;
}

private async Task<bool> SomeToDo()
{
    //Some complex and time taking calculation will be here
    return true;
}

private async Task<bool> Save()
{
    //Some complex and time taking calculation will be here
    return true;
}
```

Using `WhenAll()` has some advantage like propagating all error at once, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18311102/1876572)

Comment: Not saying you are wrong, all depends on what type of call is being used. There is a good write up on this subject done here http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-even-in.html not knowing the actual code of the project it's guessing what would be best use.

Comment: @Depechie Thanks i have better understanding from the stephancleary blog.