# Turning a method to awaitable

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to solidify my understanding of async and await.  I finally understood the whole thing about context switching (it's all magic).  I wrote a short winform program to play around with it.  Please consider the following

```
  private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        output.Text = "start";
        var intRet = await Task.Run(() => RunALot());
        output.Text += "   after run  ";
        output.Text += intRet.ToString();


    }

    private async Task<int> RunALot ()
    {

        int temp = 0;
        for (int ini = 0; ini <= 40000; ini++)
        {
            temp += ini;
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

I already have a `Task.Run` when I'm calling `RunALot.` Would I need to wrap the inside of the `RunALot` yet into another `Task.Run` and `await` that to make this truly asynchronous? Nesting context has any performance implications - how deep can I nest context?

Comment: Looks like you're confusing asynchrony and parallelism, but I can't tell what you're really asking here...

Comment: Given that your workload is unrealistic, I don't think it's possible to give a realistic answer. In reality, is your workload CPU bound or IO bound?

Comment: Task.run(() => will allocate a new thread (new context) which will make your method RunAlot() awaitable meaning that the rest of your code will not execute until it has returned a task.result.  there will be no  noticeable performance difference in this particular case.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119075/do-you-have-to-put-task-run-in-a-method-to-make-it-async

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that *async keyword does not make your code run asynchronously*. As Servy has already mentioned, RunALot() is not asynchronous method. If you want to make it async you can do something like that:

```
public static Task<int> RunALot()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        int temp = 0;
        for (int ini = 0; ini <= 40000; ini++)
        {
            temp += ini;
        }
        return temp;
    });
}
```

And this is how you can call it in button1_Click:

```
var intRet = await RunALot();
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey.  But I'm calling the method with Task.Run.  The difference here is that you wrapping the content of the method in Task.Run.  Wouldn't that be the same thing?

Comment: You get the accepted answer since your answer was correct and you have the lowest points.  With others, it's giving a dollar bill to Bill Gates :)

Answer (score 5):

`RunALot` Is not actually an asynchronous operation.  You've marked it with the `async` keyword, but the implementation of the method just does a bunch of work synchronously and then returns an already completed `Task` at the end.  Your code generates a compiler warning to tell you this.

Since `RunALot` is synchronous, if you want to create a `Task` that represents that synchronous work being done asynchronously on another thread.  You're doing that.  However, rather than having `RunALot` lie and claim to be asynchronous, you should change it's signature to have it not return a `Task`, so that it's clear to anyone calling it that it's not actually an asynchronous operation.

Comment: thank you.  One question, what is the difference between your method and vendettamit method?  I have Task.Run the method but he has the content of the method in Task.Run.  Are both methods the same?

Comment: @Zuzlx His is a worse practice, as it implies to callers that the method is inherently asynchronous, when it isn't, and requires a lot of additional overhead if the operation ever needs to be used in a synchronous context.  Async over sync is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 4):

If something is synchronous, and you just want to keep your UI thread free, keep the method signature free of async task, and wrap the call with Task.Run(). You don't want your implementations to use Task.Run() to force a signature of Async, because it isn't really Asynchronous, it's a synchronous method that you want your UI to continue to be responsive while it processes. Task.Run() in this instance gives you that.

In direct connection to your sample, you don't need the async Task signature on RunAlot, because it's a CPU bound operation and isn't asynchronous by nature.

Here's some reading I encourage you to check out: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Example of what it should be:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    output.Text = "start";
    var intRet = await Task.Run(() => RunALot());
    output.Text += "   after run  ";
    output.Text += intRet.ToString();


}

//Removed the Async Task portion of the signature as this is CPU bound work.
private int RunALot ()
{

    int temp = 0;
    for (int ini = 0; ini <= 40000; ini++)
    {
        temp += ini;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the task inside the RunALot like below.

```
 private static async Task<int> RunALotAsync()
 {
     // For CPU bound work use Task.Run, Alternate is Task.Factory.StartNew
     return await Task.Run(() =>
     {
         int temp = 0;
         for (int ini = 0; ini <= 40000; ini++)
         {
             temp += ini;
         }
         return temp;
     });
 }
```

Now await the RunALot on calling method

```
 var intRet = await RunALotAsync();
```

[Read more](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) about correct usage of `async` & `await`.

Comment: Thanks.  But why static method?

Comment: It's doesn't matter.

Comment: thanks again...great info.  So which one is better, to wrap the calling method in Task.Run (like I have done) or wrap the content of the method in Task.Run.  Are both methods the same in terms of best practices?  Performance?

Comment: If it's private method go with approach @DavidY suggested. If its a public method go with wrapping and returning task like above. Performance will be same bt keep in mind if its a cpu bound or IO bound operation.