# C# (Xamarin) - forcing event handlers to be asynchronous

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, xamarin

I have a class for doing Bluetooth communications, for the sake of argument let's say it looks something like this:

```
class Bluetooth
{
    public delegate void ByteFunc (byte[] packet);
    public event ByteFunc OnPacketSending;
    public event ByteFunc OnPacketReceived;

    public void SendPackets(List<byte[]> packets)
    {
        foreach (byte[] packet in packets)
        {
            OnPacketSending?.Invoke(packet);
            Bluetooth_Send(packet);   // Pseudo-code, takes a few more calls than this
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that events are normally synchronous (right?) so if I add an event handler like this:

```
Bluetooth.OnPacketSending += (packet) => RedrawTheEntireScreenAndAllKindsOfStuff(packet);
```

And now I call SendPackets() in the UI thread, my Bluetooth communication is slowed way down because all that UI stuff is happening instead of the Bluetooth.

The compiler won't let me say

```
public async event ByteFunc OnPacketSending
```

or

```
await OnPacketSending?.Invoke(packet)
```

and I can't use Control.BeginInvoke() because I don't know if the event handler is in a control.

and most of the examples I've seen online put the responsibility on the event handler to do things asynchronously, and I'd rather be able to enforce it.

Is it sufficient/recommended to do something simple like:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew (() => OnPacketSending?.Invoke (packet));
```

Does this use a thread pool or similar to avoid swamping the poor mobile device?

Comment: `Task.Run(() =>);` can help you. But for a complete answer to your question read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17119610/1771254

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create a delagate that returns a task.
Then you can use this delegate as Eventhandler and await it.

```
public delegate Task MyDelegate();
public event MyDelegate MyEvent;
```

And invoking it like this:

```
 await MyEvent?.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using BackgroundWorker. Basically, you start a method and then it will raise an event when it's finished.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

If you want to await this, you can use a TaskCompletionSource.