# Async/Await execution steps

Tags: c#

Can anyone explain to me why second `Working!` shows after `Done` ?

```
Stating
Doing Work
Working!
Done
Working!
Work completed
```

Second question why can't I just do like below to get Task result:

```
Task result = await LongOperation();
```

And last question is what would be the reason to use `Task.Run` on behalf with await/async for instance in my code? Where could it be used or is it not good to use it?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting");
        var worker = new Worker();
        worker.DoWork();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    public async void DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing work");

        await LongOperation();
        await LongOperation();

        Console.WriteLine("Work completed");
    }

    private async Task LongOperation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Working!");
        await Task.Delay(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Because you call `LongOperation` twice.  2. Because that's not how `await` works.  3. To call a synchronous operation asynchronously.  (In the future, please try to keep it to one question per post.)

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should avoid asking multiple questions in the same thread. Also, it would make it a lot easier for us to understand if you provided some context as to what you're asking (especially in the 1st question) means.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have declared `DoWork()` asynchronous with a return type of `void`. This makes it a "fire and forget" method that is running asynchronously. If you have `DoWork()` return a `Task` instead of `void`, you can `await` it, and that would ensure your "Done" message would occur after `DoWork()` has completed execution.

Additionally, `await` unwraps the task result, so you cannot await it and get the value at the same time. If you wish to use the `Task` result directly, do not `await` it.

There is no specific area in the code you specified where you should be using `Task.Run()`.

Answer (score 0):

There reason "Done!" appears sooner than you expect is because you do **not** have `await` in front of `worker.DoWork();` (and `DoWork` needs to return a `Task` to be able to use `await`).  So what happens is `DoWork()` returns immediately with execution deferred to another thread, and immediately goes to next line which is the console write "done".

Regarding `Task result = await LongOperation();`, `await` takes in as parameter awaitable object (i.e. `Task`), examines its `.Result` property on your behalf, extracts the result and returns it.  So you either drop `await` to get the task instance, or you put `await` to wait for task completion and extracting the actual return value of the call.

There are a few reasons to use `Task.Run` or through task factory, one example being passing lambda function for execution (possibly with closure).  I would refer to MSDN library on TPL for detailed dive.

Comment: You cannot `await` a void return type.

Comment: try to avoid void syntax no control for task fire and forget

Answer (score 0):

1. `Working` shows after `Done!` because in your `static void Main` you aren't waiting for `worker.DoWork();` to complete, so the program executes the next line. You should change `DoWork` method like this:

   ```
   public async Task DoWork()
   {
       //
   }
   ```

And change the call to it like this:

```
worker.DoWork().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

2. You can't because using `await` your `LongOperation` will not return a `Task`. For example if you had a signature like this, when you use `await` you unwrap the result:

   ```
   public Task<int> GiveANumberAsync()
   {
       return Task.FromResult(12);
   }

   int result = await GiveANumberAsync();
   ```
3. For this question I think I can't explain better than Stephen [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013523/when-correctly-use-task-run-and-when-just-async-await), where he says:

> Use Task.Run to call CPU-bound methods.

Comment: CPU bound methods is thje way of use

Answer (score 0):

Taking your questions one by one:

1. In `Main`, you do not await `DoWork`. This means that it is invoked, and then execution of the code in the `Main` continues, without waiting for `DoWork` to finish. As such, "Done" is printed to the console right away before the second "Working".
2. This isn't what the `await` keyword does. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await):

> The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes. The task represents ongoing work. [...]
>   The task to which the await operator is applied typically is the return value from a call to a method that implements the Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern. Examples include values of type `Task` or `Task<TResult>`.

Effectively, in order to `await` a method, it must have return type `Task<T>`, where T is the actual type of what you `return` in your code. Your method `LongOperation` doesn't actually return anything in this example.

3. `Task.Run` is used to run any method or block of code as a Task. It can be fired and forgotten (`Task.Run([something];`), or awaited like any other task (`await Task.Run([something]);`. See the documentation for it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx), though I'm not sure it will be much help. User [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) explained it well in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17119610/7662085) answer, along with some other pertinent information.