# Cannot Await Void in MVVM Light Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, mvvm, mvvm-light

I tried to use mvvmlight as my mvvm model but there some error I don't understand. It said I cant void cant use await. If void cant use await then what should I do in here here is my code:

```
async void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender)
{
    try
    {
        var result = await App.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(
            Constants.Scopes,
            string.Empty,
            UiOptions.SelectAccount,
            string.Empty,
            null,
            Constants.Authority,
            Constants.SignUpSignInPolicy);
        await _navigationservice.NavigateTo(Locator.MainPageViewModel);
    }
    catch (MsalException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message != null && ex.Message.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
        {
            await OnForgotPassword();
        }
        if (ex.ErrorCode != "authentication_canceled")
        {
            //  await DisplayAlert("An error has occurred", "Exception message: " + ex.Message, "Dismiss");
        }
    }
}
```

and the error is in the `await _navigationservice.NavigateTo(Locator.MainPageViewModel);`
it shows error message right this `Cannot await 'void'` what should I do here?

Comment: change `void` to `Task`

Comment: good practices for async/await : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: Remove `await` from ` _navigationservice.NavigateTo` line. That method is void and thus cannot be awaited.

Comment: You can't await `void` anywhere, not only in a Xamarin app.

Answer (score 1):

Put void returning method inside Task.Run() and await it.
Here you find better explanation. 
[Do you have to put Task.Run in a method to make it async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119075/do-you-have-to-put-task-run-in-a-method-to-make-it-async)

You can implement like this.

```
async void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender)
{
    try
    {
        ....//previous code
        await Task.Run( () =>
          {
            _navigationservice.NavigateTo(Locator.MainPageViewModel);
          });
    }
    catch (MsalException ex)
    {

        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that any code inside the `Action` passed to `Task.Run` will run on the  `ThreadPool`.  This has repercussions when the code needs to access the UI.