# Method does not get executed properly in service mode in C#

Tags: c#, task

I have implemented a background service that executes some long process work. A snapshot of how the things are arranged are as follows:

```
 Task.Run(async () =>
          {             
              await DoBackgroundJob();
           });

public async Task DoBackgroundJob() {
        MatchAndInsertIntoDb(); // call another method
}
```

The method `MatchAndInsertIntoDb` has method signature as follows:

```
public ObservableCollection<Trucks> MatchAndInsertIntoDb() {
```

The issue is that when I put breakpoints on each line, the method `MatchAndInsertIntoDb()` gets executed properly, when I press `F10` on each line.

But when the background service runs without debugging and breakpoints, the method `MatchAndInsertIntoDb()` does not seem to be executing properly. The method `MatchAndInsertIntoDb()` has a few methods in its body, like querying the local db and performing a match against another list and posting data on a remote web service.

My suspect is that since its a long-running operation, it is not getting sufficient time to complete the execution properly.

Could somebody enlighten me on this issue or help me to resolve it please ?

Comment: What are you `await`ing in `DoBackgroundJob`?

Comment: Ensuring that ` DoBackgroundJob();` gets completely executed.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. You marked `DoBackgroundJob` as `async`, but there is no `await` in that method. So why is it marked `async`?

Comment: I am unable to await `MatchAndInsertIntoDb()` as its signature is not `async`.

Comment: If you do not do anything asynchronous in DoBackgroundJob then you should not add `async` or `Task` as the result. That is not how async/await works....

Comment: I am adding Task to the method and async so as not to block the main UI thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Do you have to put Task.Run in a method to make it async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119075)

Comment: @Igor : Should all methods within the `MatchAndInsertIntoDb()` be of type `async` and all these corresponding methods should have await ?