# How do i call an async method from a winforms button click event?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have an I/O bound method that I want to run asynchronously.

In [the help docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) it mentions that I should use async and await without Task.Run

to quote

> For I/O-bound code, you await an operation which returns a Task or
>   Task inside of an async method.

How do I do this from a winforms button click event?

I have tried

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
      await doLoadJob();
}

private async Task<int> doLoadJob()
{
    await loadJob();   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `private async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: In order to truly benefit from asynchronicity, you need it all the way down. If `loadJob` is yours, make it `async` too. If it's library code, is there a `loadJobAsyc` (or `loadJobTaskAsync`) available?

Comment: It seems clear that `loadJob()` is a sync method, not an async one, so the warning you receive already has the answer: "or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread".  So use `await Task.Run(() => loadJob())` in your handler (as well as make the handler async, as others have said).  It would be better to make `loadJob()` async, if you can, but as long as it remains sync, you need to do this.

Comment: @sellotape - the OP describes their task as I/O bound, not CPU-bound, so using `Task.Run()` is usually the wrong choice.

Comment: @damien_the_unbeliever - I agree it's probably mostly I/O bound (as a database call), but if it's sync I/O it will still need `Task.Run()`, until/unless it is also made async.

Comment: @KirstenGreed - you've changed the question so much now that a coherent answer is unlikely.  Re your latest edit, I/O bound code is not magically async; it's instead usually _very well suited to being made async_. `loadJob()` appears to be sync, regardless of the nature of its activity.  As long as it's sync, you have to use `Task.Run()` to achieve what you want.  The quote you just added says "For I/O-bound code, you await **an operation which returns a Task** or Task inside of an async method" - does `loadJob()` return a `Task`?

Comment: @sellotape sorry about the edits they are all to try and articulate my problem which has not changed.  LoadJob returns void

Comment: @KirstenGreed - then, assuming it can't be made async ("source code not available"), you need `Task.Run()` or the handler will block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do you have to put Task.Run in a method to make it async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119075/do-you-have-to-put-task-run-in-a-method-to-make-it-async)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119075/do-you-have-to-put-task-run-in-a-method-to-make-it-async?rq=1  helped me a lot.  I reverted the question to be like the original so that the answer makes sense.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your `button_Click` method needs to be `async`.  Place a `async` between `private` and `void`.

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     await LongOperation();
}
```

Comment: You can't move the form around because System.Threading.Thread.Sleep is affecting your main (app) thread.

Comment: any suggestions how to simulate the io bound event?

Comment: @KirstenGreed post that into a **new question**.  Stop changing the scope of your original question.  Your original post shows no such code

Comment: Because you misrepresented the problem. It solveed the problem you presented. Accept that and make a new question and maybe spend al ittle more time providing RELEVANT examples. See, there is no sleep in your code sample, ergo it can not cause a problem. The question you DID ask got answered.