# Winforms C#: async initialize

Tags: winforms

I have a `Winform` C# application, that has a `DataGridView`. I intend to load data from `Azure table storage` into it meanwhile the form is `initializing`. I'm afraid if I load so much data from `Azure table storage`, my app will be crashed. Can I use `Async` load data from `Azure table storage` in form constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you'd typically do this kind of work is in the `Form_Load` event. For example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await RefreshDataAsync();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await RefreshDataAsync();
        }

        private async Task RefreshDataAsync()
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            listBox1.Items.Clear();

            try
            {
                var data = await GetDataFromDataSourceAsync();
                foreach(var item in data)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                button1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you'd create a "refresh data" method, and have your `Form_Load` event call that. Since you segregated the refresh code, you could have other things call it as well, such as a button.

WinForm events such as `Form_Load` or button click events can be made asynchronous by simply adding the `async` keyword to them. More info about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664291/how-do-i-call-an-async-method-from-a-winforms-button-click-event).

Comment: I really appreciate for your support, it helped me to solve my problem.