# C# WPF Async at startup

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, asynchronous, async-await

I try to build a simple WPF application and have a `listbox` in the `MainWindow`.
The background is that it pings some machines but I want that the GUI already opens and whenever the ping finishes, the `listbox` should update the content.

Let me show my code.
MainWindow.xaml.cs

```xml
        public ObservableCollection<String> LbStatus
        {
            get { return BL.GetStatus(); }
        }
```

BL.cs

```cs
        public static ObservableCollection<string> GetStatus()
        {
            List<string> hostnames = new List<String>(GetHostnames());

            ObservableCollection<string> status = new ObservableCollection<string>();
 
            foreach(string hostname in hostnames)
            {
                Task<string> task = Task.Run(async () => await 
 PingHost(HM.GetHostname(hostname)));
                status.Add(task.Result); 
            }
            return status; 
        }
```

```cs
        static public async Task<string> PingHost(string hostname)
        {
            Ping x = new Ping();
            try
            {
                PingReply reply = await x.SendPingAsync(hostname, 5000);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    return "Online";
                }
                else
                    return "Offline";
            }
            catch (Exception excep)
            {
                //exception handling
            }
        }
```

I think the problem is that my program waits for `task.result`. But in my head, it should just skip and return nothing and whenever it's finished it should return the correct string. But (and that's the whole reason why I do this) the GUI should already start.

I hope my question makes sense and someone can help me with that :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Fundamentally, the issue here is that properties simply cannot be async. Period. The work-around is to invoke an async method (properly, of course), which when the _awaited_ async operation completes, _sets_ the property. The property itself must be implemented normally. See duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you introduce a few changes.
First, you have a very dubious implementation of the `LbStatus` property.
In such an implementation, each time this property is accessed, a new collection will be created, which could potentially cause: their different states; simultaneous call several times of the `BL.GetStatus()` method. And there are many other problems associated with the presence of multiple collection instances, but when the view "thinks" that this is the same instance.
By offering you this implementation of this property:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _lbStatus;
public ObservableCollection<string> LbStatus
{
    get 
    {
        if (_lbStatus == null)
            _lbStatus = BL.GetStatus();
        return _lbStatus;
    }
}
```

The second problem, in the method `BL.GetStatus()` - you need to return the collection without waiting for its completion.
Therefore, the loop for filling it should be in a separate asynchronous method.
The `BL.GetStatus()` method should call this asynchronous method, but not wait for it to complete.

I suggest you this implementation:

```
public static ObservableCollection<string> GetStatus()
{
    ObservableCollection<string> status = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    FillStatus(status);

    return status;
}

public static async Task FillStatus(ICollection<string> status)
{
    foreach (string hostname in GetHostnames())
    {
        status.Add(await PingHost(HM.GetHostname(hostname)));
    }
}
```

Another option for implementing the property, taking into account the division of the method into two parts.
It will only use the asynchronous part.

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _lbStatus;
public ObservableCollection<string> LbStatus
{
    get 
    {
        if (_lbStatus == null)
        {
            _lbStatus = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            BL.FillStatus(_lbStatus);
        }
        return _lbStatus;
    }
}
```

Taking into account the use of the collection in UI elements, its change should take place in the main UI thread.
To do this, you will have to pass the Dispatcher to the method.

```
public static async Task FillStatus(ICollection<string> status, Dispatcher dispatcher)
{
    foreach (string hostname in GetHostnames())
    {
        string item = await PingHost(HM.GetHostname(hostname));
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => status.Add(item)))
    }
}
```

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _lbStatus;
public ObservableCollection<string> LbStatus
{
    get 
    {
        if (_lbStatus == null)
        {
            _lbStatus = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            BL.FillStatus(_lbStatus, Dispatcher);
        }
        return _lbStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the help and input. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to the property getter. First, this is a really good question to get background on before continuing: [Do you have to put Task.Run in a method to make it async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119075/do-you-have-to-put-task-run-in-a-method-to-make-it-async)

Having that reference, your method PingHost is written properly to be awaited, but it being `async` does not necessarily mean it is not going to block the calling thread. <s>This has to do with how you're calling it, by a property getter - which is done synchronously.</s> You call it from a synchronous method GetStatus, and then are accessing that synchronous method through a property getter. And so, despite calling an `async` method PingHost, it's not being awaited and therefore is blocking the calling thread.

***Edit note:** Even if this was written to properly await through different calls, property getters are accessed synchronously so the below explanation still applies.*

This brings up a second reference to read up on, related to asynchronous getters. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13735418/15744261) is really touching on what you're trying to do, particularly item two in that answer:

> A value that can be used in data-binding but must be calculated/retrieved asynchronously. In this case, either use an async factory method for the containing object or use an async InitAsync() method. The data-bound value will be default(T) until the value is calculated/retrieved.

This person wrote a really nice blog post explaining how to implement this, I encourage you to check it out: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and good resources!