# How do I pass a non-awaitable action to a method that takes a Func<Task>?

Tags: c#, async-await

Suppose I have a method as follows...

```cs
public static async Task DoIt(Func<Task> doit) {
  // Do something first
  await doit();
  // Do something last
}
```

I can pass in an awaitable function as follows...

```cs
await DoIt(() => Task.Delay(1000));
```

If I want to pass in something non-awaitable, I can do it like this...

```
_ = DoIt(() => Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("Hi")));
```

...but this seems quite ugly. Is there a neater way of doing this?

Comment: From [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119075/do-you-have-to-put-task-run-in-a-method-to-make-it-async) it looks like `Task.Run()` is the cleanest way to wrap a synchronous method to return a `Task`.

Comment: Anything that returns `Task` is awaitable, so the question may be posed incorrectly.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `Task.Run()`?

Comment: Just mark the lambda `async`, as in: `_ = DoIt(async () => Console.WriteLine("Hi"));`

Comment: @ewerspej I don't have a problem with it, I'm just trying to look for a cleaner syntax. There's quite a lot of noise in that second call

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Hmm, good point! Thanks for the observation

Comment: @madreflection Thanks, that's a great suggestion. Do you want to post it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel: I suggest accepting John Wu's answer instead. Unlike my glib suggestion, that answer doesn't produce a warning about the lambda being async without awaiting anything.

Comment: @madreflection True, but yours is neater! Will accept his though. Thanks again

Comment: Sure, but it's important to clear all warnings, and suppressing them is dirty business.

Comment: @madreflection Agreed 100%. I'm a bit OCD about warnings myself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the action is an async, non-awaitable method (e.g. `async void`) there isn't really a proper way to return a task. There is no way to return a task that signals its completion when the async void method finishes.

If the action is a synchronous method, you can just return `Task.CompletedTask`.

```
_ = DoIt(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hi"); return Task.CompletedTask; } );
```

Answer (score 3):

You could consider adding a `DoIt` overload that has an `Action` parameter, and delegates to the primary `DoIt(Func<Task>)`:

```
public static Task DoIt(Action action)
    => DoIt(() => { action(); return Task.CompletedTask; });
```

The `action` is captured by the `() =>` lambda, so this approach has a minuscule overhead (a small object is heap-allocated on each call).

Be aware that the `action` will be invoked on the context of the caller. It might be invoked on the same thread that invoked the `DoIt`, and depending on the specifics of the code block `// Do something first` it might even be invoked synchronously.